# Java - Reg expression using groups

Tags: java, regex

From a string, I need to pull out groups that match a given pattern.

An example string: `<XmlLrvs>FIRST</XmlLrvs><XmlLrvs>SECOND</XmlLrvs><XmlLrvs>Third</XmlLrvs>`

Each group shall begin with `<XmlLrvs>` and end with `</XmlLrvs>`. Here is a snippet of my code...

```
String patternStr = "(<XmlLrvs>.+?</XmlLrvs>)+";

// Compile and use regular expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
matcher.matches();

// Get all groups for this match
for (int i = 1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

The output is `<XmlLrvs>Third</XmlLrvs>`. I am expecting group first and second but those aren't being captured. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are iterating over the groups when you should be iterating over matches. The `matches()` method checks the entire input for a match. What you want is the `find()` method.

Change

```
matcher.matches();

for (int i = 1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

to

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Note that the + in the regex needs to be removed, or everything will be matched at once, and not in three iterations.

Comment: I don't agree with that, the .+? is an non-greedy quantifier. But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Removing the + at the tail of the expression and using the while control statement suggested did just the job. Thanks

Comment: @molf: Right you are, didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

 `String patternStr = "<XmlLrvs>(.*?)</XmlLrvs>";

 String text = "<XmlLrvs>FIRST</XmlLrvs><XmlLrvs>SECOND</XmlLrvs><XmlLrvs>Third</XmlLrvs>";

 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);`

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
               System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
 }

The output is FIRST,SECOND,Third